# How to open android app with voice command and pass data to it

Tags: android, google-voice-actions, voice-control

I have an app which is not distributed with Google Play. Is it possible to launch it with voice control and additionally pass some additional data to it? For example with a command like "Open X app and do Y"

From what I've read Google Voice Actions are not available for apps not shipped with Google Play. Is there an alternative?